# How to change multiple folder names in powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I would like to make a script that would take a certain word in the name of the folders.
example:

> How the folders are:
>
> 23_copied
>
> 24_copied
>
> 25_copied
>
> 26_copied
>
> How I wanted:
>
> 23
>
> 24
>
> 25
>
> 26

What I want is to take the word "_copied" from the name of these folders.

I tried to follow this manual but got no results:
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-6)

can you help me?

Comment: Can you share the code you already wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path "*_copied" -Directory | % { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name -replace '_copied$', '') }
```

Each directory ending with `_copied` is renamed with new name excluding the `_copied` substring at the end of the original name (`$` marks end of the string value).

Answer (score -1):

This can be used to start...

Get-ChildItem -Path "**copied" -Recurse | select { $*.FullName.Replace(" _copied", "")}

The path must be adapted.